# npm global installations are installing but the commands don't work

Tags: npm

I've tried to install stuff like nodemon and PM2, but when I try using the commands it says this:
`'pm2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Could you please check, if the `Path` environmental variable contains the `C:\Users\{your_user}\AppData\Roaming\npm` path? If not, please add it and restart the command line. Please let me know, if it helped.

Comment: User Variables or System Variables? @tenkmilan

Comment: I think both of the is fine. If you want to have this environmental variable for the other users as well, than system variable.

Comment: I checked and they are all good.

Comment: Commands still don't work though.

Comment: Do you have any *`.cmd `files in `%appdata%/npm`?

Comment: No. For some reason they install in the `C:\Users\user\npm` file

Comment: That is unusual, but in this case I suggest to add the `C:\Users\user\npm` path to the `Path`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try doing that.

Comment: I fixed it, I just changed the global installation prefix.